# Error mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host desconocido

Tags: php, mysqli

estoy en mis primeros pasos de programación en **PHP** y me encuentro con este **error**.

[image: Este es mi archivo de configuración]
Este es mi archivo de configuración

[image: Este es mi archivo de conexión]
Este es mi archivo de conexión

[image: Este es el error que me sale en el navagador.]
Este es el error que me sale en el navagador.

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: 
 Host desconocido. in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\config\Conexion.php on 
 line 4

 Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: 
 getaddrinfo failed: Host desconocido. in 
 C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\config\Conexion.php on line 4

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\config\Conexion.php on line 7
Falló la conexión a la base de datos: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo 
failed: Host desconocido.
```

**Servidor de base de datos**

- Servidor: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
- Tipo de servidor: MariaDB
- Versión del servidor: 10.1.28-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
- Versión del protocolo: 10
- Usuario: root@localhost
- Conjunto de caracteres del servidor: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

**Servidor web**

- Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.11
- Versión del cliente de base de datos: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407  $Id: b396954eeb2d1d9ed7902b8bae237b287f21ad9e $
- extensión PHP: mysqliDocumentación curlDocumentación mbstringDocumentación
  Versión de PHP: 7.1.11

**Sistema Operativo**
Windows 10

Comment: Bienvenido. Ten en cuenta que en Stackoverflow ***1 código vale más que mil imágenes***. Si hubieras puesto el texto del código en lugar de las imágenes todo se nos facilita... también a ti que no tienes que andar capturando imágenes que en este caso sirven para muy poco. Tu conexión nunca va funcionar, ya que el contructor de MySQLi espera los datos así: `$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario", "contraseña", "basedatos");` no necesita que le digas cuál es el host, cual es el usuario, etc... él lo sabrá por el orden en que pongas las cosas. Cambia cada valor por el nombre de la constante.

Comment: ok muchas gracias por la observacion de las imagenes, encuanto a lo que comentas, de las indicaciones en codigo, esas son ayudas visuales del IDE es phpstorm realmente no estan ahi esas palabras.

Comment: Entendido, además de eso, `DB_HOST` y todas las demás constantes son eso, nombres de constantes, por lo tanto **deberías ponerlas todas sin comillas**, ya que al usar las comillas, lo que estás diciendo es que el host se llama `"DB_HOST"`, y así con todas las demás... Lo correcto sería: **`$conexion=new mysqli (DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);`** Si vieras lo incómodo que es tener que ir subiendo, para mirar la imagen y ver como se escribe cada una y luego bajar para escribirla en el comentario. Si puedes, cambia las imágenes por el código, por favor. Gracias.

Comment: Bingo, eso era, muchas gracias había pasado horas leyendo sobre la sintaxis y no me había percatado de las comillas. muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando tú escribes esto:

```
define ("DB_HOST", "localhost");
```

Estás definiendo una constante que se llama `DB_HOST`, cuyo valor es `localhost`.

Cuando llegue el momento de usar el valor de dicha constante, tú debes usarla sin comillas, ya que, si usas comillas nunca obtendrás el valor `localhost` sino una cadena entre comillas.

Haciendo eso en tu actual código, lo que estás diciendo es que el host se llama "DB_HOST"... Lo mismo ocurre con las demás constantes. Entonces, pasa al constructor los nombres de las constantes definidas, sin comillas:

```
$conexion=new mysqli (DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

---

Para más detalles, puedes consultar la [documentación sobre `define` en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.define.php). En el Ejemplo #1 se usa la constante como explico en esta respuesta.